# Component is not a known element [Angular]

Tags: angular

I'm currently working for the first time with Angular. I have a module called Api-Lab and a component called Category-Card. The structure of of my project is:

```
-app
    -[+]api-lab
        -[+]category-card
            category-card.component.ts
        api-lab.component.ts
        api-lab.module.ts
    app.module.ts
    app.routing.ts
```

In api-lab.component.html I get the error in the title in this part of HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-8 " *ngFor="let category of apiList">
            <api-lab-category-card [image]="category.image" [icon]="category.icon" [title]="category.title"
            [description]="category.description" [buttonLink]="category.buttonLink"></api-lab-category-card>
        </div>
```

This is the api-lab.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ApiLabComponent } from './api-lab.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared';
import { CategoryCardComponent } from './category-card/category-card.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule],
  declarations: [ApiLabComponent, CategoryCardComponent],
  exports: [ApiLabComponent]
})
export class ApiLabModule {}
```

This is the category-card.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-lab-category-card',
  templateUrl: './category-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-card.component.scss']
})
export class CategoryCardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  @Input() image: string;
  @Input() icon: string;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() description: string;
  @Input() buttonLink: string;
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

And finally this is the app.module.ts:

```
import { ApiLabModule } from './api-lab/api-lab.module';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  // return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
  // modifichiamo la sede di default dei file di traduzione
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/translations/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  //...declarations
  ],
  imports: [
    HomeModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    ApiLabModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    TranslatorService,
    StyleService,
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I looked at other problems like mine but i couldn't solve the issue. Surely I missed some import/declaration. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector you have specified in the `category-card` component is `app-api-lab-category-card`, but you've referenced it as `<api-lab-category-card>` in `api-lab.component.html`.

Either change the selector to drop `app` from the start, or change `api-lab.component.html` to reference `<app-api-lab-category-card>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `<app-api-lab-category-card></app-api-lab-category-card>` instead. It needs to match the selector of the component found in `category-card.component.ts`

Answer (score 1):

Your `api-lab.component.html` template has `api-lab-category-card` but your components selector is `app-api-lab-category-card`.

When you use the `ng generate component some-component-name` command, the CLI will automatically prepend the "app" as the prefix. You can modify this by changing the "prefix" attribute of your project in your `angular.json` file.